# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_97769b8b/requirements.txt (line 2))

Tags: python, django, heroku

while deploying my Django app Heroku it shows this error although all the requirements are already satisfied when I install it manually, my os is ubuntu 20, using pip3 for installation, Django 3.0.1

```
git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 88, done.
Counting objects: 100% (88/88), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (80/80), done.
Writing objects: 100% (88/88), 926.04 KiB | 10.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 88 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.2
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting appdirs==1.4.4
remote:          Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_97769b8b/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_97769b8b/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to mygamlaapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/mygamlaapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem, if answer is yes.Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The error is causing due to your `requiremets.txt` file. Because `pip` is trying to install `apturl` package from your mentioned location which is mentioned in your `requirements.txt` (line 2) file which is `/tmp/build_97769b8b/requirements.txt` as mentioned in your question.
So edit your `requirements.txt` file and only use `apturl==0.5.2` instead of:
`apturl==0.5.2  @/tmp/build_97769b8b/`